# Stream Error in the HTTP/2 framing layer: bigrquery commands error in R studio but not in Base R

Tags: r, curl, google-bigquery, rstudio

I have several programs written in R that use bigrquery to run queries, table deletes, and upload data. These were all written in R studio with R version 3.3.1 on a windows 7 machine. No issues at all running them over and over.

A new hire is trying to run the same exact programs on Windows 10. Same version of base R and R studio. The packages all install fine and there are no errors of any kind. But commands sent to bigquery through the code (i.e., query_exec, insert_upload_job) will submit, but they hang for several minutes, then return the following error:

Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
Stream error in the HTTP/2 framing layer

These queries run in 2 seconds normally. These commands run fast in base R on the same machine with no errors.

I have a Windows 10 laptop at home so I installed everything the same way, and it is displaying the same behavior. The commands run fine in base R but "hang" in R studio for several minutes before returning the error above.

What is weird is that periodically the same commands run fine in R studio, but most of the time we get the error.

I looked for this issue and found:
r-hub/rhub#32

But I am not able to figure out how to turn off http2 on the client side to see if that would help.

One thing I noticed is that when I check the curl version with:
curl::curl_version()
It shows version 7.47.1 on my Windows 7 machine (the one that works) and does it does not show an http2 value.

On the Windows 10 machine, it shows curl version 7.53.1, and shows an http2=TRUE parameter.

I haven't been able to figure out how to deprecate the version of curl on the Win10 machine to see if that would fix the issue.

In any case, I would think if it's an issue with the latest version that other folks would be having the same issue.

I also posted this to the bigrquery github issues page but so far no one has responded.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `curl:: handle_setopt()` lets you set curl handle options. You're looking to ensure `http_version` is set to `2` which maps to `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1` in the cURL library. However, I don't use bigquery enough to know how to get that handle passed into it for ops.

Comment: Thank you  hrbrmsfr.  I can't figure out how to pass this option into the handle either--I'll add your comment to the github post for this issue as it may help the bigrquery developer to identify the fix.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to downgrade [`curl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/index.html) to workaround the [error in the HTTP2 framing layer](https://github.com/cloudyr/googleCloudStorageR/issues/71#issuecomment-332781571). Instead, you could use one of the methods below to set a specific `http_version`.

### Method 1 - httr

For those of you who use the [`httr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/index.html) package, you can specify the preferred HTTP version directly like this:

```r
# 0 stands for CURL_HTTP_VERSION_NONE (see http_version values below)
httr::set_config(httr::config(http_version = 0))
```

This workaround was suggested [here](https://github.com/cloudyr/googleCloudStorageR/issues/71#issuecomment-332781571).

### Method 2 - curl or RCurl

Another (lower level) example of how to set the options directly using [`curl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/index.html) is provided in the package vignettes [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/vignettes/intro.html#configuring_a_handle). An excerpt:

```r
h <- curl::new_handle()
curl::handle_setopt(h, http_version = 0)
# then use the handle to make a request
# see curl vignettes for an example
```

For an [`RCurl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html) example, see [TLS v1.1 / TLS v1.2 support in RCurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130293/tls-v1-1-tls-v1-2-support-in-rcurl/42163908#42163908).

### http_version values

The curl HTTP version numbers are available in the [C enum](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum#Explanation) defined in the [curl header file on GitHub](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/0fd4427f40b9b5a10c53650fabc9d049e0d33c23/include/curl/curl.h#L1921) (the link is to an older commit):

```cpp
enum {
  CURL_HTTP_VERSION_NONE, /* 0, setting this means we don't care, and that we'd
                             like the library to choose the best possible
                             for us! */
  CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0,  /* 1, please use HTTP 1.0 in the request */
  CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,  /* 2, please use HTTP 1.1 in the request */
  CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0,  /* 3, please use HTTP 2 in the request */
  CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS, /* 4, use version 2 for HTTPS, version 1.1 for HTTP */
  CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_PRIOR_KNOWLEDGE,  /* 5, please use HTTP 2 without HTTP/1.1
                                           Upgrade */

  CURL_HTTP_VERSION_LAST /* 6, *ILLEGAL* http version */
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a workaround by doing the following steps:

1. Removed the curl folder in my base R win-library subfolder (when I tried installing an older version of curl it wasn't able to automatically remove the current version)
2. Install curl version 0.9.7 (this version does NOT use http2)

   ```
   install.packages("https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/curl_0.9.7.zip", repos=NULL,type="source")
   ```

Run `curl::curl_version()` to confirm no http2 parameter.

Longer term, someone still needs to fix the issue.  I've posted it on the github repository for bigrquery, but I'm not sure if they need to fix it or if the fix needs to happen in the curl() function.