# RCurl with Salesforce.com returns Unsupported SSL protocol version

Tags: r, curl, salesforce, libcurl, rcurl

I'm literally ripping out my hair here.  It seems that I can't query even the front page of login.salesforce.com

```
require(RCurl)
#Works, note I removed sslversion
getURL("https://www.google.com/", cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"), .opts=c(followLocation=T, verbose = TRUE), ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)

#Does not work
getURL("https://login.salesforce.com/", cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"), .opts=c(followLocation=T, sslversion=5L, verbose = TRUE), ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
```

When I type in `RCurl::curlVersion()$ssl_version` it returns `[1] "OpenSSL/1.0.0o"`

According to https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221207&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.ca%2F&type=1 they recently disabled TLS 1.0 so you need 1.1 support.  This leads me to think that I need a newer update of libcurl that can do TLS 1.1

I was clued in to the 5L from this other stack overflow post here: [TLS v1.1 / TLS v1.2 support in RCurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130293/tls-v1-1-tls-v1-2-support-in-rcurl)

I'm thinking that I don't actually have that level of ssl in my current RCurl or Curl package because when I start typing ssl into RStudio I get the following suggestions:

[image]

Anyway, I should also note that my work computer is highly locked down with security software and I don't have access to install programs or whatnot.  I can drag/drop binaries of course.  So I went and downloaded the latest libcurl binaries and installed them on C:\CURL -- I even put C:\CURL\BIN in my path.  But nothing works.

**So long story short, how do I get RCurl to use a TLS 1.1 SSL Certificate?**

Comment: I recall having a problem like this. I think it's related to the OS. You should try spinning up an Ubuntu/Debian based Rstudio instance on a free-tier AWS instance to see if your code runs.

Comment: It's more related to the woefully outdated CA file that ships with RCurl. Try downloading a new one from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html and use that.

Comment: @hrbrmstr that was a good guess but unfortunately didn't fix it

Comment: * Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to login.salesforce.com:443
> CONNECT login.salesforce.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: login.salesforce.com:443
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
< 
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* Unsupported SSL protocol version
* Closing connection 0
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Unsupported SSL protocol version

Comment: Can you try using the `curl` package with `httr` instead? It is definitely a more modern interface and has better defaults as it works with the underlying `libcurl` (the same `libcurl` that RCurl uses)

Comment: I would recommend using the **salesforcer** package which does not use **Rcurl** (**curl** and **httr** packages  instead which support TLS v1.1)